# next.js code works in run dev but not run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The problem is with the useAddress() funciton in run dev when console logged it returns undefined undefiuned then address however in the run build/start it just returns undefined. How do I go about fixing this.

```js
import { useAddress } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Username from '../components/Username';
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {

    let address = useAddress();

    console.log(address)
    
        if (address) {
            return (
                <>
                    <Head>
                        <title>home</title>
                        <link rel="icon" href="/drum.svg" />
                    </Head>
                    <Username address={address} />
                </>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <>
                    <Head>
                        <title>home</title>
                        <link rel="icon" href="/drum.svg" />                
                    </Head>
                    <Link href="/">
                    <a className="absolute pt-1 text-xl font-semibold transform -translate-x-1/2 top-1/2 left-1/2">click here to log in</a>
                    </Link>
                </>
            );
        }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you define `ThirdwebProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

Imperative code is too unpredictible in React. You should use `useEffect(()=>{console.log(address)},[])` instead and it will probably work the same in both settings.

Comment: returns undefined should I just use a different sign in function

Comment: Yes I expected it to be undefined actually. What do you want to do? If you put your console.log() after your setAdress() that should print the address. Actually imperative code is fine but you have to be able to find out when it executes and it's not always easy

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your code. Well I don't know for sure. What is your useAddress code?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

```
import { useAddress } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Username from '../components/Username';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const Home = () => {
    const [address, setAddress] = useState(false)

    useEffect(()=> {
        setAddress(useAddress())
    }, [])

   
    
        if (address) {
            return (
                <>
                    <Head>
                        <title>home</title>
                        <link rel="icon" href="/drum.svg" />
                    </Head>
                    <Username address={address} />
                </>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <>
                    <Head>
                        <title>home</title>
                        <link rel="icon" href="/drum.svg" />                
                    </Head>
                    <Link href="/">
                    <a className="absolute pt-1 text-xl font-semibold transform -translate-x-1/2 top-1/2 left-1/2">click here to log in</a>
                    </Link>
                </>
            );
        }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: cant call hooks inside useEffect. This was my first thought too.